# Smart Folders : How to omit certain folders

Tags: finder, smart-folders

I made a smart folder of all my .psd (Photoshop) files, so I can easily access them.

However, my smart folder has .psd files from apps such as ZBrush that use .psd format in their program. It also brings up .psd files from my Creative Cloud.

Is it possible to tell Smart Folders to exclude these folders?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a Saved Search that excludes a specific folder from the results?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56973/how-can-i-create-a-saved-search-that-excludes-a-specific-folder-from-the-results)