# Exclude files and folders from Finder search

Tags: mac, finder, search

I seek to excluding files when searching in Finder:

When I perform a search in Finder, it will also show system and application files.

I know I can save a search which only searches my user, but I want to know if this is possible to turn off for a regular Finder window search or perhaps by creating a saved search that excludes a specific folder from the results?

This has been asked before:
[How can I create a Saved Search that excludes a specific folder from the results?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56973/how-can-i-create-a-saved-search-that-excludes-a-specific-folder-from-the-results)

but unfortunately none of the solutions worked for me for reasons that aren’t easy to list here.

I'm on High Sierra.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). Regarding your question, saying, *"This has been asked before, but none of the answers worked for me"* doesn't help us at all to help you, as we don't know what you've tried and therefore what didn't work? Can you please edit your question to include this info so we're not likely to suggest things you've already done. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I will edit my question.

Comment: Great edit, the question still needs a little more cleanup so I consolidated what was three questions into one. Feel free to enumerate why the answer(s) on the linked question failed you if no one has a good answer in a few days or a week.

Comment: Applications and System folder are on the same level as yoor home directory. you can avoid searching them by searching a directory on the same level as Applications.

Comment: Following upon @jmh 's comment, you might be searching in "This Mac" while you might want to use current folder or previous search if you specify it to be User folder. This setting can be changed in Finder preferences -> advanced.

Comment: jmh: that's the problem. In my user I have: Applications, Library (invisible, but stil show up in search??), Music, Movies, Documents, Downloads, Pictures +++

I want to search all these folders at once, but NOT Applications and Library (unnecessary files show up).

How do I do this?